# Valgrind did not show a function name

Tags: valgrind

I'm now testing my program with valgrind.

The result is quite weird.

So what I expected is just like below

```
    ==19364== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==19364==    at 0x20ED4E25: ipConvert (in /usr/lib/libhpip.so.0.0.1)
    ==19364==    by 0x20EB7595: sclpml_read (in /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hpaio.so.1.0.0)
    ==19364==    by 0x424595: _scanner_scan_thread_gthread_func (scanner.c:7155)
```

In above example, there are "at" and "by" but in my result I just got "at"

```
    ==7807== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==7807==     in use at exit: 3,940,633 bytes in 1,119 blocks
    ==7807==   total heap usage: 2,466 allocs, 1,347 frees, 4,848,416 bytes allocated
    ==7807==
    ==7807== 24 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 14
    ==7807==    at 0x4836994: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
```

So everything printed is the same. No "by" just "at".

What am I suppose to do?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

When you compile it, you have to remove `-formit-frame-pointer` flag.

Good luck!